# redirect_uri_mismatch with https-only app on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, appharbor

I've deployed MVC 5 site to AppHarbor, got the https-only app working thanks to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/runesoerensen/915869) linked by AppHarbor support.

When I connected to Google OAuth 2 provider locally, everything worked fine - I can log in without problems, but when I try it on AppHarbor, I get error on login "redirect_uri_mismatch". I've got proper key and secret set for web app, the problem is with path, for some reason my page responds with redirect_uri starting with "http://..." instead of "https://..." which I've set in the google project console -  (other than that it's the same uri).

I've tried [this workaround](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/workaround-for-generating-absolute-urls-without-port-number) for URL-based problems, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

As I don't think switching to http for /signin-google would be a good idea - how to fix it?

Comment: are you using the Google .net client lib?

Comment: No, default MVC5 library for remote authorisation, part of Katana project. Here's the tutorial I've used: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on - it's using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google libraries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.google%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: I have spent months trying to get Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google to work.  I gave up.  If you do get it to work please post the code.

Comment: Well I've coded it almost exactly as in the tutorial I've linked in a previous comment. After adding it on google project I was able to log in through my google account. I think I can upload stripped out project somewhere (but later).

Comment: @DalmTo: here's default mvc 5 project with working google auth over OAuth 2: https://github.com/mrowa/mvc5-with-owin-google-auth it's just three changes and it already works on my local machine with IIS Express. Probably you'd like to see this: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleAuthenticationHandler.cs instead ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's a few months later but I hope this will help someone. I had exactly the same problem with AppHarbor load balancers and loosing the "https" in the redirect_uri string. The simplest solution that I found is to register a few lines of code like a middleware in Startup.Auth.cs before any registration of external login providers:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (string.Equals(context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"], "https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            }

            await next.Invoke();
        });
```

This simple middleware checks for AppHarbor header "X-Forwarded-Proto" and if exist just add a correct Scheme property. If you look at the [Katana's code](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler.cs) correct Scheme property solve the problem:

```
    ...
    string requestPrefix = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host;
    string redirectUri = requestPrefix + Request.PathBase + Options.CallbackPath;
    ...
```